# using the facebook graph to display profile pictures ...what if someone changes their username?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a web app that will retrieve basic Facebook user information, among them also the profile photo, via

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/picture?width=100&height=100
```

I plan on storing that variable in my database so that I can display the profile photos in the web app.

Now, I'm wondering what happens when someone changes their Facebook username from "jimmysmith" to "jamesdoe", for example? I assume that my saved URL of

```
https://graph.facebook.com/JIMMYSMITH/picture?width=100&height=100
```

will stop working? Is there any way around this?

Or will it still work because Facebook redirects the old username to the new username, maybe? I found no evidence of that, however. I have no way of testing it, either.

The way I retrieve it via FQL is:

```
$fql    =   "select uid, name, email, birthday from user wher.... etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the user IDs instead.
Usernames will not be query-able in v2.0 API.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading for more information.